# Is there a special one-parametric solution of an equation $y^n+y^{n-1}=x^m+x^{m-1}$?

Tags: polynomials

Two weeks ago user759001 [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757149/on-the-diophantine-equation-xm-1x1-yn-1y1-with-xy-over-integer) on integer solutions $x>y\ge 2$ of a Diophantine equation
$$x^{m-1}(x+1)=y^{n-1}(y+1)\tag{1}$$
for integers $m,n\geq 2$.
The only known solutions are $(x,y;m,n)=(3,2;2,3)$ and $(98,21;2,3)$. User2020201 [showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757149/on-the-diophantine-equation-xm-1x1-yn-1y1-with-xy-over-integer/3770266#3770266) that $m<n$. I conjectured that there are no solutions when $m|n$ and proved the conjecture in particual cases (when $(m,n)$ is $(2,6)$, $(3,19)$, or $(4,12)$. Also I guess I have a proof when $n=2m$), see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757149/on-the-diophantine-equation-xm-1x1-yn-1y1-with-xy-over-integer/3771331#3771331) answer.

According to [G], Diophantine equations with two variables of degree greater than two have infinitely many (integer) solutions only in very rare cases. In particular, by a special and very complicated method K. Zigel’ (Siegel?) showed the following

**Theorem.** Let $P(x,y)$ be an irreducible polynomial of two variables with integer coefficients of a total degree greater than two (that is, $P(x,y)$ contains a monomial $ax^ky^s$, where $k+s>2$). (The irreducibility of $P(x,y)$ means that it cannot be represented as a product of two non-constant polynomials with integer coefficients). If an equation $P(x,y)=0$ has infinitely many integer solutions $(x,y)$ then there exist an integer $r$ and integers $a_i$, $b_i$ for each $-r\le i\le r$ such that if in the equation $P(x,y)=0$ we make a substitution $x=\sum_{i=-r}^r a_it^i$ and $y=\sum_{i=-r}^r b_it^i$ then we obtain an identity.

For user759001’s equation for fixed $n>m\ge 2$ we have $P(x,y)=y^n+y^{n-1}-x^m-x^{m-1}$. GreginGre [showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775566/is-a-polynomial-ynyn-1-xm-xm-1-irreducible-in-bbb-zx-y/3776450#3776450) that $P(x,y)$ is irreducible. It looks plausible and easy to show that there is no such substitution, but, unfortunately, I am not a specialist in the respective branch of mathematics, so I decided to ask MSE community for help. Thanks.

*References*

[G] Gel’fand A.O. *Solutions of equations in integer numbers*, 3rd edn., Moscow, Nauka, 1978, in Russian.